# Change $\int_0^\sqrt{2}\int_x^\sqrt{4-x^2}\sin\left(x^2+y^2\right)\:dy\:dx$ to polar coordinates

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

This is a homework problem, so please do not give more than hints. I must convert
\begin{align}
\int_0^\sqrt{2}\int_x^\sqrt{4-x^2}\sin\left(x^2+y^2\right)\:dy\:dx\tag{1}
\end{align}
to polar coordinates. This is my attempt:
\begin{align}
\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}\int_{\color{red}{2\cos\left(\theta\right)}}^{\color{red}{2\sin\left(\theta\right)}}\sin\left(r^2\right)r\:dr\:d\theta,\tag{2}
\end{align}
but I am unsure about the $\color{red}{\text{red}}$ limits, because while I am solving I end up at
\begin{align}
\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos\left(4\cos^2\left(\theta\right)\right)}{2}-\frac{\cos\left(4\sin^2\left(\theta\right)\right)}{2}\:d\theta\tag{3}
\end{align}
after a single round of $u$-substitution. There's no way it should end up here, unless it's really easy and I'm just not thinking...

I think the upper limit is $\color{red}{2\sin\left(\theta\right)}$ because a substitution of $2\cos\left(\theta\right)$ into $\sqrt{4-x^2}$ results in
\begin{align}
\sqrt{4-x^2}&=\sqrt{4-4\cos^2\left(\theta\right)}\\
&=2\sin\left(\theta\right),
\end{align}
and the lower limit is $\color{red}{2\cos\left(\theta\right)}$ by direct substitution as before.

Here is my $u$-substitution:

Let $\xi=r^2$, then $d\xi/2r=dr$, resulting in
\begin{align}
;\;\int r\sin\left(r^2\right)\:dr&=\frac{1}{2}\int \sin\left(\xi\right)\:d\xi\\
&=\frac{-\cos\left(\xi\right)}{2}=\frac{-\cos\left(r^2\right)}{2}\bigg|
\end{align}
Thus,
\begin{align}
\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}\int_{2\cos\left(\theta\right)}^{2\sin\left(\theta\right)}r\sin\left(r^2\right)\:dr\:d\theta&=\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}\left[\frac{-\cos\left(r^2\right)}{2}\right]_{2\cos\left(\theta\right)}^{2\sin\left(\theta\right)}\;d\theta.
\end{align}
Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: The advice is always the same for this sort of question: draw a picture, and then you know what the region actually looks like.

Answer (score 2):

firstly, you must sketch the region
[image]
$$\int_{\pi /4}^{\pi /2}\int_{0}^{2}\sin(r^2)rdrd\theta $$

Answer (score 1):

Below is the region over which you are integrating.

[image]

Can you now fix the limits of $r$ and $\theta$?